# Strange mootools window dragging behaviour

Tags: javascript, position, mootools, positioning, modal-dialog

I have a drag-able mootools modal window. 
The content of the window is a iFrame.
I drag the window from inside the iFrame. (it drags but shakes a lot during dragging)

Live link **[here](http://www.sofiesrenting.com/v2/en/test_house/drag_test.php)**.

**Question**:

- why this strange drag behaviour?
- the iFrame leaves its border, empty, on the origin place. How to avoid this?

Thankfull for ideas/tips on were to search for problem.

---

My code:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
document.getElementById('iframe2_footer').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);         
});

function mouseUp()
{
window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}
function mouseDown(e){
var div = parent.document.getElementById("price_info");
offY= e.clientY-parseInt(div.offsetTop);
offX= e.clientX-parseInt(div.offsetLeft);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}
function divMove(e){
var div = parent.document.getElementById("price_info");
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.setPosition({ x: e.clientX-offX });
div.setPosition({ y: e.clientY-offY });
}
```

**EDIT:**
Just did some log to the `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` (Thank you @Nils for the idea) and got this:

```
...
450 -168
340 -218
460 -173
347 -221
468 -176
355 -224
478 -179
364 -226
483 -182
374 -229
...
```

Quite big steps. Any idea why?

Comment: Hehe nice implementation, but I highly doubt you're going to be able to fix it - this looks like unexpected consequences of an unexpected use case to the rendering engine. I'd seriously consider implementing the Ajax solution instead and solve all problems in one go, this seems like a dead-end road to me.

Comment: add a console.log(e.clientY, e.clientX) in your code to check that the values look OK. You might have to change context in Chrome to be able to inspect the iFrame.

Comment: Good idea @Nils, just did that and added info on the question.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone has already mentioned, I also do not see how this could be solved, at least without additional draggable block element outside of iframe. Maybe you're too focused on this specific problem so you have overlooked the possibilities of simple-modal plugin that you use. This plugin has implemented draggable effect, why not use it. If you open simple-modal.js file, in line 72 is html template for the plugin that looks like:

```
  "<div class=\"simple-modal-header\"> \
    <h1>{_TITLE_}</h1> \
  </div> \
  <div class=\"simple-modal-body\"> \
    <div class=\"contents\">{_CONTENTS_}</div> \
  </div> \
  <div class=\"simple-modal-footer\"></div>"
```

Simply adjust the template to your preferences, so if you want to have a draggable footer, unlike the default header, try this:

```
  "<div class=\"simple-modal-body\"> \
    <div class=\"contents\">{_CONTENTS_}</div> \
  </div> \
  <div class=\"simple-modal-footer\"></div> \
  <div class=\"simple-modal-header\"><h1>{_TITLE_}</h1></div>"
```

Apply some CSS and that's it, modal and draggable iframe without unnecessary complications.

EDIT:

**Why this strange drag behaviour?**

Simple test which shows where the problem is, put this code inside drag_test.php and  iframe.php:

```
// script
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    document.getElementById('mousepos').innerHTML = e.clientX+' - '+e.clientY;
});
// body
<p id="mousepos"></p>
```

Move the mouse around, and you'll see that one window does not knows for mouse position when the mouse is inside another window. This is because in DOM hierarchy is window object the top-level object.

**The iFrame leaves its border, empty, on the origin place. How to avoid this?**

Border that you see is left over from simple-modal div. When you set `position: absolute;` to iframe it detaches the frame from container, so container remains on the original place.

Comment: Thank you Danijel for looking at this. Using the simple-modal's drag capacities is an idea but not the question I ask here. My "on-course" investigation, whith your ideas and others here is: "is it possible?".   I need the iFrame to be drag-able. Thanks!

Comment: Well despite the bounty I'm not going to fix it, because I very seriously doubt it's possible, and even if it is it's going to be a hacky tacky solution that won't survive browser updates and cross-browser consistency.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, I aprecciate your efford. You are probably right. But I am as I am (fixed idea person) and I will try to make it work :) If I fail, I learn a lot anyway. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are reinventing the wheel. You use MooTools. Use [Drag + Drag.Move](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag.Move) from MooTools-more:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/bEdX8/

```
new Drag.Move(document.getElement('div.container'), {
    handle: document.getElement('.dragme'),
    modifiers: {
        x: 'margin-left',
        y: 'margin-top'
    }
});
```

seems to work w/o any glitches.

also, your code is very laggy.

```
var div = parent.document.getElementById("price_info");
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.setPosition({ x: e.clientX-offX });
div.setPosition({ y: e.clientY-offY });
```

this runs on every move? so first thing wrong: price info won't change. cache it.
position won't change. set it and forget it.

`setPosition` is called twice when you can call it once:

```
div.setPosition({ 
    y: e.clientY - offY,
    x: e.clientX - offX
});
```

although you have the element - set `div.style.left = nnn`; directly to avoid function calls at all.

AND `offY` and `offX` are global variables (bad) and every reference is 2 scope chains up... seriously, no wonder it is laggy. when you do low level stuff that needs to be performant, javascript needs be micro-optimised and you need to really apply yourself.

also, your code wont work in IE and you don't use the mootools api at all. element -> `document.id('someid')`, events: `element.addEvents({ event1: fn, event2: fn));` etc etc.

mootools does not just return an element. it also extends it in IELT9 and sets up element uid, storage etc.

if your objective is to be able to move the position of the iframe on a page with an unknown js framework and you need to bind this from within the iframe, then it's understandable what you are trying to do. same principles for perf need to apply, though.

Comment: Thank you for your input again. I follow your suggestion and make a dragable div outside the iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You could try another strategy if you absolutely need to use an iframe. In the iframe :

```
window.addEvent('mousedown',function(e) {
    var start={x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY};
    window.addEvent('mousemove',function(e) {
        window.parent.postMessage({dX:start.x-e.clientX, dY:start.y-e.clientY});
    });
});

window.addEvent('mouseup',function(e) {
    window.removeEvents('mousemove');
});
```

On the main window :

```
window.onMessage=function(event) {
// do something with event data
}
```

It should only work in some browsers, the most recent of course. Let me know if you succeed.

Comment: Interesting approach! thank you for giving it a look. I tried your idea but cannot get data from `window.onMessage`. My javascript knowledge is limited. But I managed to get data thru: `window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);`, it produced the same unstable result...

Comment: sorry, it's window.onmessage. Anyway it seems unusefull for you.