# What is more correct "setPosition" or "style.left/right"?

Tags: javascript, position, mootools

I am trying to make a mootools drag on a iFrame.

**Qestion:**

Is it more correct to use

```
var div = parent.document.getElementById("price_info");
div.setPosition({ x: e.clientX-offX });
```

OR

```
var div = parent.document.getElementById("price_info");
div.style.left = (e.clientX-offX) + 'px';
```

This info will hopefully help me fixing a bigger problem... ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580140/strange-mootools-window-dragging-behaviour))

Comment: `setPosition` is non-standard. Right?

Comment: Interesting @techfoobar, can you explain that? do you mean its mootools and not vanilla JS?

Comment: Yes, kind of.. Actually, I did not see the mootools tag! :)

Comment: btw, this may not work in old IE since you don't extend the element and it does not inherit from the mootools changes to `Element.prototype` - whereas `div.style.left` will or `parent.document.getElement('#someid');` to return a mootools extended el.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes down to the same thing. `setPosition()` writes to the element's `style` object, just like you would do manually.

I suppose if you've taken the decision to build your code in a framework you should use its API where possible, unless there is a specific reason to ignore it and use vanilla JS in its place.

Also, `setPosition()` returns the element(s) affected, whereas `.style` does not, so this may be a factor with regard to chaining, for example.